# Creating "Data Source View" with Stored Procedures?

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, adhoc

I'm trying to create a Data Source View, to use with Adhoc SSRS Reports.

These are the steps to make Adhoc reports.

Data Source > Data Source View > Data Source Model > Report Builder > Report.

When I try to create a Data Source View it only lets me choose from a the selected Data Source's Tables/Views. There is no option for Stored Procedures. Is there any possible way to create a Data Source View with Stored Procedures?

Answer (score 0):

This article on Code Project seems to be what you're looking for: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20540/Using-StoredProcs-with-Parameters-in-SQL-Reporting

Comment: That article shows how to add Stored Proc's to Regular reports. I'm looking for Data Source View's with stored proc's.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/6aea5c68-939e-4203-ba41-288e4bfc6eb6) from Microsoft *Stored procedures are not supported by Report Builder*. Although that is an old response, Report Builder 1.0 was the last version of Report Builder to support models anyway so no more DataSourceView/Model from Microsoft have been added so I believe that is still accurate. I also checked [the latest docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156272%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) related to Report Builder & Report Models and I don't see any mention of stored procedures.

If stored procedures and end user reporting is important to you, our [ActiveReports Server product](http://www.activereportsserver.com/) includes a "Logical Data Model" that is roughly equivalent to Report Models in Report Builder 1.0 / SQL Server 2005 but we have added a lot on top of it including support for [creating entities from stored procedures](http://community.activereportsserver.com/knowledgebase/articles/167389-reporting-on-a-stored-procedure).